# Excel crashes after attempting anything VBA related

Tags: vba, excel, dll, crash

Could someone please help with this visual basic related crash issue. I have an Office 365 Business installation, version 1808 (Build 10730.20102 Click-to-Run) on a Windows 10 system. Whenever I try to edit, create or record a macro (even from a blank, plain xlsx file) my Excel just crashes and restarts. I've been in contact with Office 365 support and we've tried the following:

- We turned antivirus off
- We tried Excel in safe mode
- We disabled COM Add-Ins and checked the "Compile on Demand" is turned off: https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/the_microsoft_excel_support_team_blog/2012/09/07/excel-crashes-in-vbe7-dll-running-or-enabling-macro/
- We updated device drivers
- We ran the repair tool for Office apps
- We created a new Windows profile
- We added a registry key for the VBE7.DLL error we found in session log: https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/the_microsoft_excel_support_team_blog/2012/09/07/excel-crashes-in-vbe7-dll-running-or-enabling-macro/
- Uninstalled and reinstalled Office apps

Still the issue persists. Any other ideas would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What type of computer are you using and what MS excel did you download 32 bit or 64bit?

Comment: What antivirus are you using? If you say Bitdefender then we're in business.

Comment: Also, try deleting your temp files. Sometimes the macro's will get stuck especially after a crash.

Comment: Have you tried running in safe mode? If not, try that, if it works then it's an issue related to an add-in.

Comment: Have you tried to update MS Office? Make sure is completely finishes updating.

Comment: Ricky, I have a Dell Vostro 15, 5000 Series and 32bit installation.

Comment: xTwisteDx, I had AVG which has since been uninstalled.

Comment: Try adding more registry keys (CompileOnDemand and ForceVBALoadFromSource) described in the forum: https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsserver/en-US/c9044eea-f01d-47af-ae8e-731f80e347ee/excel-crashes-in-vbe7dll-running-or-enabling-macro?forum=excel

Answer (score 0):

## Suggestion #1

Try deleting your temp files.

```
1. Close all programs.
2. Window+R keys to open RUN.
3. Type %temp% and Enter.
4. Hit Ctrl+A, then Delete.
```

Restart PC

## Suggestion #2

Launch it in safe mode, if it works then the issue is related to an add-in.

```
1. Close all programs.
2. Windows+R keys to open RUN.
3. Type excel.exe /safe then enter. 
4. Profit?
```

## Suggestion #3

`Options=>Advanced=>(unchecked)Extend Data Range Formats and Formulas.`

Comment: Thanks xTwisteDx. I've tried both and still no luck unfortunately.